# Validate and submit a form

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, post

Why is it not correct to validate and submit a form using this code?

My intention is to send the data obtained in the form (name and email) to the file *1f_ok.php*, which will be responsible for saving the data into the database.

```
<form id="new_item_post" class="fm" method="post" action="<? $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data" name="procedim" 
      onSubmit="MM_validateForm('nombre','mailcontacto');return document.MM_returnValue" 
      ondblclick="Submit_seguro(this)">
```

to process

```
<?php
  if ($response != null && $response->success) {
    echo "<script>alert('Submitted form'); location.href='1f_ok.php'</script>";
  } else {
?>
```

Comment: where\how are `$response` and `$response->success` defined?

Answer (score 1):

Client-side (javascript) form validation is merely for the benefit of improving User Experience (UX). It is not a substitution for server-side (PHP) validation. You need **both**, but they serve different purposes.

Javascript should definitely make the experience of submitting the form *better* for the end-user, but it will not make the process of *preventing server-side failures* any better, because no one is required to run your javascript in order to send an HTTP request to your server.

For example, let's say your PHP expects the user to supply a valid email address and a password that's at least 8 characters long. If you use javascript to prevent the request from being sent to the server because it did not meet these requirements, and provide some additional information in the browser to alert the user of this failure, then it only stands to serve the end-user better. Otherwise, the alternative is that the request has to get to the server first, before it fails, and the serve is then responsible for somehow informing the user of the failure.

This gets unwieldy in certain cases. Let's say, for example in the case where the user is uploading a large file. If the server requires that the file size not exceed a certain amount (let's say 100MB), javascript can be used to let the end-user know that this file is too large **before** we even attempt sending it to the server. This means the user doesn't have to wait for the upload to complete first before they're informed that it's unacceptable by the server.

This doesn't mean the server doesn't need to validate the size as well. It still needs to perform the same validation to prevent any application/system failures and enforce any required application/system constraints.

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to JavaScript, I have been using PHP for a while and I would like to say that using JavaScript for form validation is a bad habit, it is always recommended to use a server side language to validate forms such as PHP or Python. So maybe create your own success/error messages or continue using the alert box, but when it comes to validating user input and submitting data, always depend on a server side language!

Comment: As stated in previous (now deleted answers) blanket statements like "using JavaScript for form validation is a bad habit" are bullshit. You are correct about the server side validation, but that doesn't mean that client side validation is a bad habit.